# My XMLHttpRequest is removing the first character on send when it is a $

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest

I've created the XMLHttpRequest and I'm sending it with post. I have a string that sometimes starts with multiple $, for example $$$ABCD. The request is in JavaScript and it's being sent to a function in C#.

When the string does not start with $$$, it shows up fine. However when it is $$$ABCD, it arrives as $$ABCD.

I check that the string is correct just before I call send in JavaScript.

Any help is appreciated.

**Javascript**

```
this.ChangeFilter = function (filter)
    {       
Url = "NoNameHere.asmx/FunctionThatIsCalled";
        PostData = "ProfileName={0}&Filter={1}&userKey={2}";

        EventHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        EventHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = VoidCallback;
        EventHttpRequest.open("post", Url, false);
        EventHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        EventHttpRequest.send(PostData.replace("{0}", sessionProfile)
                                        .replace("{1}", filter)
                                        .replace("{2}", userKey));
}

Filter here in JavaScript is $$$ABCD and correct

**C#**
public void FunctionThatIsCalled(string Profile Name, string Filter, string user Key)
    {}
```

Filter shows up here in C# is $$ABCD, missing the first $ before I do anything

Comment: You need to provide the code.

Comment: Try wrapping your values in `encodeURIComponent`